# What is a distro-agnostic way determine the OS install date?

Tags: linux, date

I am on a CrunchBang machine and trying to write a script that needs to have the OS install date as a reference.

I searched and found this command:

```
ls -lct /etc | tail -1 | awk '{print $6, $7, $8}'
```

It prints

```
Mar 31 21:24
```

I did not understand the `tail -1` part, but was able figure out that $6 $7 $8 are the 6th 7th 8th occurrences of the last line that the command is referencing.

However, I realized that the year cannot be included as the year was not displayed in the `ls -ltc` command.

Some people suggested finding the date `/etc` was created and some checking the `/var/log/syslog` etc. I thought these might be a little specific to the distro.

What is your recommendation for a truly distro-agnostic way to find the OS install date?

Comment: Why do you think checking `/etc`'s creation date is distro-specific?

Comment: I recently read that there are some distros that have a different file system hierarchy like gobolinux and was under the impression that there might be more distros similar to gobolinux.

Comment: I think checking /etc is more portable than assuming an ext filesystem. Or just check for the oldest directory in `/`.

Comment: Just for completeness, I'll note that the output of ls shows the time when it is less than six months old, and the year when it is more than six months.

Comment: @Kevin if you unpack an archive while preserving permissions, the oldest directory/file can be way older than the system install date.

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve that goal... anything I found is either filesystem or distribution specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the assumption is that you have an ext{2,3,4} filesystem, and you formatted the root filesystem when you installed the OS (and didn't do upgrades from another OS without a wipe), you can use dumpe2fs:

```
% dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/vg_desktop-lv_root 2>&1 |grep 'Filesystem created'
Filesystem created:       Sat Jul 23 04:28:07 2011
```

Comment: Was the output being redirected to somewhere or a file, because nothing happened when I run the command.

Comment: You'll have to supply the device for your root filesystem, instead of /dev/mapper/vg_desktop-lv_root.  Check the output of `df /` to get it.  I'm sure you could automate it.

Comment: I realized I had a `_` instead of `-` when typing the command. I get the date now. Thanks.

Comment: Or that you didn't backup, reformat, and restore.

Comment: My filesystem is reiserfs. Imho, looking for /etc is a better approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no distro-agnostic file in /etc that can be guaranteed to have timestamps on it that date back to the initial install.  That's why I figured it'd be better to go look at the timestamps on something that is less prone to the package manager changing.

Comment: Also, there is no 'creation time' attribute for files or directories, at least, nothing you can get through a stat().

Comment: Expecting users to use ext{2,3,4} is as distro-agnostic as expecting "/etc" to exist. I even think "/etc" is more likely to exists.

Comment: Yes, but there's nothing about /etc that is guaranteed to provide installation time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any formal method for this.

What I have always done is:

```
touch /install-`date +"%F"` && chattr +i /install-20*
```

That creates a file named 'install-' followed by the current date (if ran today it would be install-2012-04-03) and sets it as immutable, so it can't be deleted by accident.

Then is it just a matter of looking at that file to see when the OS was installed.