# Find out exact installation time of CentOS

Tags: centos, filesystems, system-installation, date

I installed CentOS on my laptop about 8 month ago, and 
I want to know when **exactly** I installed it , how can I do that in CentOS 6.4 ?

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate. The dup it points to shows distro-agnostic ways only, this one includes those + distro specific ways to determine installation time.

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35566/what-is-a-distro-agnostic-way-determine-the-os-install-date

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### tune2fs

You can use the command `tune2fs` to find out when the filesystem was created.

```
$ tune2fs -l /dev/main/partition |grep  'Filesystem created'
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/dm-1 |grep  'Filesystem created'
Filesystem created:       Sat Dec  7 20:42:03 2013
```

#### which disk to use?

If you don't have `/dev/dm-1` you can use the command `blkid` to determine your HDD topology.

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-swap: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4"
```

You can also find out what filesystem a directory is coming from using the `df -h .` command.

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root   50G  9.3G   38G  20% /
```

### From kickstart .cfg file

You can also look at the date this file was created, assuming it wasn't deleted.

```
$ sudo  ls -lah ~root/anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-------. 1 root root 1.3K Dec  7 21:10 /root/anaconda-ks.cfg
```

### From RPM

Another method would be to find out when the package `setup` was installed. This package is rarely updated, only from version of version of distro, so it should be fairly safe to query it in this manner.

#### Example

```
$  rpm -qi setup | grep Install
Install Date: Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:32 PM EST
```

Another package that has similar qualities to `setup` is `basesystem`.

```
$ rpm -qi basesystem | grep Install
Install Date: Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:47 PM EST
```

Lastly you could just take the full list of installed packages and get the last few to see what their install dates were.

```
$ rpm -qa --last | tail 
nhn-nanum-fonts-common-3.020-8.fc19.noarch    Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:47 PM EST
basesystem-10.0-8.fc19.noarch                 Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:47 PM EST
m17n-db-1.6.4-2.fc19.noarch                   Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:46 PM EST
gnome-user-docs-3.8.2-1.fc19.noarch           Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:45 PM EST
foomatic-db-filesystem-4.0-38.20130604.fc19.noarch Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:45 PM EST
mozilla-filesystem-1.9-9.fc19.x86_64          Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:35 PM EST
dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-5.fc19.noarch        Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:34 PM EST
telepathy-filesystem-0.0.2-5.fc19.noarch      Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:33 PM EST
setup-2.8.71-1.fc19.noarch                    Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:32 PM EST
fontpackages-filesystem-1.44-7.fc19.noarch    Sat 07 Dec 2013 08:46:31 PM EST
```

Comment: there is no `dm-1` file in my `/dev` directory

Comment: @AlirezaFallah - see updates.

Comment: actually the last two tip worked perfect, thanks

Comment: @AlirezaFallah - yeah I like to show all the method for Q's like this, b/c you never know a system's setup, it's always handy to have many options.

Answer (score 4):

I assume during the installation you have formatted your file system?

If that's the case you can use the `tune2fs` utility to see the creation date that's stored in the super block of your root file system.

Assumed your root file system is `/dev/sda3` you could do do this:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda3
```

In the output there should be a field called `Filesystem created` like here:

```
Filesystem created:       Wed Oct 31 15:30:21 2012
```

Comment: how can I find out the  file system path ? there is `sda` and `sda1` and `sda2` in my `/dev/` directory .

Comment: you can look at the output of the `mount` command. the one that is mounted to `/` is the root file system.

Answer (score 2):

### Method

#### RPM

via command `rpm -qi basesystem`, in CentOS 6.10, its output is

```
#rpm -qi basesystem
Name        : basesystem                   Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 10.0                              Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 4.el6                         Build Date: Wed 10 Nov 2010 05:12:57 PM PST
Install Date: Fri 01 Jun 2018 05:06:56 PM PDT      Build Host: c5b2.bsys.dev.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Base       Source RPM: basesystem-10.0-4.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 0                                License: Public Domain
Signature   : RSA/8, Sat 02 Jul 2011 09:00:48 PM PDT, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Summary     : The skeleton package which defines a simple Red Hat Enterprise Linux system
Description :
Basesystem defines the components of a basic Red Hat Enterprise Linux
system (for example, the package installation order to use during
bootstrapping). Basesystem should be in every installation of a system,
and it should never be removed.
```

extraction command

```
rpm -qi basesystem 2> /dev/null | sed -r -n '/^Install Date[[:space:]]*:/{s@[[:space:]]{2,}.*$@@g;s@^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*(.*)$@\1@g;p}'
```

output

```
Fri 01 Jun 2018 05:06:56 PM PDT
```

#### /etc/

via file create time under dir `/etc/`

extraction command

```
ls -lact --full-time /etc/ | awk 'END {print $6,$7,$8}'
```

- -l     use a long listing format
- -a, --all    do not ignore entries starting with .
- -c     with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file status information)  with -l: show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort by ctime
- -t     sort by modification time
- --full-time    like -l --time-style=full-iso

output

```
2018-06-01 17:06:54.101999993 -0700
```

### Addition

If you wanna format date, you may consider use command `date`

```
#echo 'Fri 01 Jun 2018 05:06:56 PM PDT' | date +'%F %T %z %Z' -f -
2018-06-01 17:06:56 -0700 PDT

#echo '2018-06-01 17:06:54.101999993 -0700' | date +'%F %T %z %Z' -f -
2018-06-01 17:06:54 -0700 PDT
```